# PHP ftp_connect() fail

Tags: php, ftp

Very simple problem but one which I am unable to solve. Why would I get a ftp_connect() fail?

```
$conn = ftp_connect("www.server.com");
```

Have tried SSL connect. Intrestingly I had no problem with this ftp_connect() on this server until recently when I started getting error messages. Not too sure what triggered this perhaps an update as the code was not altered.

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** Found this in Plesk : *Shell access to server with FTP user's credentials - Forbidden*
Have no idea if its relevant

Comment: You should post the error you are getting, this would help identify the problem.

Comment: Firewall change? FTP service disabled?

Comment: Just getting or die message I left for myself, is there a way to obtain more detailed error messages ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after lots of fiddling (asking someone else) this is the solution I found...

```
$conn = ftp_connect(localhost);
```

Well the simplest solution is the best. This works as the code is situated on the server to which it is trying to connect.